# Would other players in my game also be on Hardmode after beating the Wall of Flesh?

Tags: terraria

My friend and I were playing multiplayer on my world. We defeated the Wall of Flesh. Does he have Hardmode unlocked?

Answer (score 5):

**Hard mode is specific to the world, not the player.**
 If the other player goes back to a world where Wall of Flesh has not yet been defeated, that world is still in normal mode and requires Wall of Flesh to be defeated to enter hard mode.

Comment: Also do not get confused with a Hardcore character vs a Hardmode world :)